# On the fly grouping in Crystal - Can this be done?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a statement report with 6 groups that has always worked well.  We have introduced a new field that, when set to 'Y', needs to change the group order and paging.

When the field is blank or 'N', the group order needs to be:
A - AR
B - AR Acct#
C - Bus Unit
D - AR Date
E - AR Apply_to
F - INV Acct#
Page Footer summarizes everything for that AR account and it sorts all AR for the parent company by Bus Unit and child account within the report.

When the field is 'Y', the group order needs to be:
A - AR
B - AR Acct#
F - INV Acct# - with a simple page break
C - Bus Unit
D - AR Date
E - AR Apply_to
The page footer still summarizes everything for the parent account, but the Child account now needs to be aggregated before the Bus Unit, date etc.

I have 2 reports and separately, both reports work fine, I need to know how to dynamically change the report's grouping based upon a field in the parent record.

There is already CrystalGroupSelection in the code that runs the report and that is the basis for the first and 2nd AR grouping. That needs to stay.  I am just not sure how to tell the report to print one group order if the field is blank or 'N' and a different group order when the field is 'Y'.

Can someone assist?  Is this even possible?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you can't change or reorder the grouping levels of a report at run-time.  However, there may be another way if you are able to evaluate the boolean field before running the report.  Then you could create 2 reports with different groupings, then evaluate the field to determine which report to run.